# Image is parsing but not displaying all images in android using daimajia library

Tags: android, json

this is my code

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShopDeals.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JsonParser
                .getJSONfromURL("http://gpstracker.mpiricsoftware.com/lopez/feed.php");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            //jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

            jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonobject);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                //map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(i);

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("img","http://gpstracker.mpiricsoftware.com/lopez/uploads/"+jobj.getString("image"));
                Log.e("img",jobj.getString("image"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {


        for (String name : map.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(ShopDeals.this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(map.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(ShopDeals.this);

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);


            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);

        /*listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new SlidingImage_Adapter(ShopDeals.this, arraylist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);*/

        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

this is my logcat error:

```
 06-20 14:45:20.795 2706-2983/evip.gohybrid.com.evip E/log_tag: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"7","song":"pop.mp3","image":"wordpress-banner.jpg","desc1":"Sermon1","desc2":"Sermon1","desc3":"Sermon1","desc4":"Sermon1"},{"id":"9","song":"1.png","image":"1.png","desc1":"catb","desc2":"cabt","desc3":"cad","desc4":"dsad"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
 06-20 14:45:20.797 2706-2983/evip.gohybrid.com.evip E/img: wordpress-banner.jpg
 06-20 14:45:21.004 2706-2983/evip.gohybrid.com.evip E/img: 1.png
```

can you please tell whats the problem..?

Comment: Use `jsonObject ` instead of `jobj ` to get Image key value

Comment: its giving me same error....all images are parsed but only one image is displaying

Comment: can you show full json data

Comment: [{"id":"7","song":"pop.mp3","image":"wordpress-banner.jpg","desc1":"Sermon1","desc2":"Sermon1","desc3":"Sermon1","desc4":"Sermon1"},{"id":"9","song":"1.png","image":"1.png","desc1":"catb","desc2":"cabt","desc3":"cad","desc4":"dsad"}]

Comment: what is the return type of funtion JsonParser.getJSONfromURL("your url")

Comment: its String: public static String getJSONfromURL(String url)

Comment: still no effects....its displaying the same image while its sliding

Comment: because of you put img as key in Hashmap so all time its return Only one Image path value

Comment: now what can i do...?

Comment: see my answer n try it chnage in both funtion doinbackground n onPoastExcute code

Comment: thanks....its working well..

Comment: welcome enjoy Android Code.....

Comment: i really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
               String  jsonobject = JsonParser
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://gpstracker.mpiricsoftware.com/lopez/feed.php");

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    //jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

                   JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonobject);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put(String.valueOf(i),"http://gpstracker.mpiricsoftware.com/lopez/uploads/"+jsonObject.getString("image"));
                        Log.e(String.valueOf(i),jsonObject.getString("image"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

and in postbackground

```
 @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                int i=0;
                for (String name : map.keySet()){
                    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(ShopDeals.this);
                    // initialize a SliderLayout
                    textSliderView
                            .description(name)
                            .image(map.get(String.valueOf(i)))
                            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                            .setOnSliderClickListener(ShopDeals.this);

                    //add your extra information
                    textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                    textSliderView.getBundle()
                            .putString("extra",name);


                    mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
                    i++;
                }
                mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
                mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
                mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
                mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);

    /*listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new SlidingImage_Adapter(ShopDeals.this, arraylist);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);*/

                pDialog.dismiss();

            }
```

chnage code and try it

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your `doInBackground`:

```
jsonobject = JsonParser.getJSONfromURL("http://gpstracker.mpiricsoftware.com/lopez/feed.php");
```

If `jsonobject` is an `JSONObject`, there is your error. Root of response is n fact an `JSONArray`.

If you change your `jsonobject` to a `JSONArray` type it should go through.